# plain url or relative path?

Tags: php, path

I have on my hosting two instances, one for each domains. I have a principal domain, and during a little time i would like to put a part of the content under other domain. My resources (js, img, css...) are on the principal domain, and i have a same header and footer (PHP).

So, if i would like to include the header of the principal domain on my second domain, i do it like `include("../../www.domain.com/htdocs/includes/header.php");`

In this file header.php, paths for resources are relative like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/libs/animate/animate.min.css" />`

So, if i include header.php on my other domain, resources are not loaded because there are not on this domain. So, i have to change all the resources links for plain url ? Or create a "personnal" CDN ? There is a difference beetween loaded a relative path or plain url ?

Comment: That's called an **absolute** URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a difference beetween loaded a relative path or plain url ?

You have to use an absolute URL, starting with `http://` or simply `//` if you want to access to the files on a different domain. A relative path, without `//` at the beginning, will always use the current domain.

In other words, you'll need an absolute URL as soon as you want to access to another domain. You can use an absolute or relative URL to access to the files on the current domain.

You can also use [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_%28Unix%29) (or [junctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) on Windows) in order to serve same files on both domains.